# Trace a polygon

Tags: qgis, editing

How do I trace a polygon using different layer. 
Ex: A and B are two area boundary. Boundary of B area should be near the river. How do I add area C to the B area?
[image]

Comment: Should the boundary of area B be near the river, or should the river be the boundary?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the snapping options to `Advanced`:

[image]

You then select your polygon layer (my Scratch layer) and the river layer (National Trails in my example).

You can then turn on [auto trace](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/projects/autotrace/TraceDigitising/) (the magnet icon), and create new polygons to fill the area between B and the river,

[image]

When you finish the polygon it will clip against the existing polygons and follow the river.

[image]

Once you are happy it is simple to select all of the polygons and merge them together.

[image]